# Apache DirectorySlash Off - Site breaks

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

If i set `DirectorySlash Off` in my `.htaccess` file and call the directory **without** the trailing slash i get an `403-Forbidden` from my server. If i call it with slash everything works fine.

Could anyone explain why? Here are my fully anonymized `.htaccess`:

```
# GLOBAL CONFIG
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectorySlash Off
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder/index.php [L]
# END WordPress

# REMOVE WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you know per the documentation, when `DirectorySlash` is set to `Off`, requests to `/folder` do not have `DirectoryIndex` evaluated. This means that the request will not be automatically mapped to `/folder/index.php`.

`mod_dir` performs this check in the "fixup" phase of the request processing. `mod_rewrite`, which is responsible for your `RewriteRule` definitions, also performs its processing in this phase when you specify the rules in a  `.htaccess` file.

However, it was programmed with an awareness of modules like `mod_dir`, and includes a check to make sure that the current directory was requested with a trailing slash. If not, it declines to handle the request, since doing so might lead to undefined behaviour.

The request then moves on to the content-generation phase, which, since the request was not mapped to a real file, is handled by `mod_autoindex`. Given that `Indexes` are disabled on your host by default, `mod_autoindex` returns `403 Forbidden` which is what you see.

Note that since `DirectoryIndex` is not evaluated, even if `mod_rewrite` *were* to process the request, it would still fail, because no auto-resolution to `index.php` would occur, and your rule

```
RewriteRule . /folder/index.php [L]
```

wouldn't match, because the `.` requires a match on something (but the request would be blank).

Enabling `DirectorySlash` prevents this scenario by correcting the prevented actions in all of the previously mentioned scenarios except the last note, which is taken care of by the fact that `DirectoryIndex` maps the request to `index.php` anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! Easy to understand too, if i read your Answer.

Comment: But what if we want to obfuscate our directory structure and still use `mod_rewrite` for each request? Let's say I have a site with a `/private` directory. Apache would redirect me to `/private/` if I request `/private` if `DirectorySlash` is `On`, thus letting information disclosure to take in. What if I just want to send `/private` to my `index.php` front controller?

Answer (score 12):

With Apache 2.4 you can allow rewrites in .htaccess files by setting `RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash`.

```
 Changes with Apache 2.3.16
 ...
 *) mod_rewrite: Add the AllowNoSlash RewriteOption, which makes it possible
    for RewriteRules to be placed in .htaccess files that match the directory
    with no trailing slash. PR 48304.
    [Matthew Byng-Maddick <matthew byng-maddick bbc.co.uk>]
 ...
```

See [Apache documentation of mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions)

Answer (score 2):

I think because when you turn DirectorySlash off, it disable the autocorrection of the url and it is trying to show the directory list but fortunately you have probably disabled this somewhere (or in file permissions) so it sends a 403-Forbidden. I guess that when you turn it on, it works normally.
From what I understand from the docs, it is not very good to use DirectorySlash off for security.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: Laurent, thank you for your answer. I've read the **security warning** in the apache docs too but i need to understand what went wrong here.

By the way directory listing is per default disabled at my webhost backend.

Comment: You `rewriteBase is /folder/` so you need the ending slash on the url to match. You can set it to `/folder` and I think it should work without the ending slash.

Comment: I get also an 403 if i follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom already answered, there is special option for RewriteOptions, but only for Apache 2.3.16+, so if you, like me, have an apache of the older version, then you cannot rewrite url for same directory, because apache doesn't know about this directory.

Example:
"GET /somedir" will point to `<Directory /var/www/html/public>` in [rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog), but(!) requested filename (%f) in access log will still `/var/www/html/public/somedir/` - this is crazy apache logic. And apache will show you either 503 (without Options +Indexes) or directory listing (otherwise) with wrong urls such as /subdir/ instead of /somedir/subdir/

So, I've found only one worked solution for me - using aliases:

```
AliasMatch "/somedir$" "/var/www/html/public/somedir/index.html"
```

Hope this helps someone else in 2020+ :D