# forbidden when post array comes in??

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permissions

I have this [page](http://posnation.com/lease.php) which is a big form and its posting to it self. The problem is that when you click on the "Submit Application" button on the bottom the error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /lease.php on this server.
```

In my .htaccess I have lots of stuff but i think this is causing the problem which i cant remove because I need it

```
DirectorySlash Off

# RewriteRule ^cafeteria-pos/index\.php$ - [L] 
# RewriteRule ^cafeteria-pos/?$ /cafeteria-pos/index.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/index.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
```

here is my declaration of the php form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" id="app_form" name="app_form" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
```

its the same url...what is going on...any ideas

Comment: Have you checked the generated HTML source to verify that `action` contains the expected value?

Comment: yes I have and I even hardcoded /lease.php and same results

Answer (score 0):

Could be, simply, permissions. If you can have ftp/shell access, change permissions to 644 for lease.php

Comment: i changed it to 755 and still nothing

Comment: You might also try disabling "DirectorySlash Off" (see here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258879/apache-directoryslash-off-site-breaks ... for a reference of DirectorySlash causing the Forbidden error)

Comment: they maybe the issue...ill look into a bit more