# Hiding extension with htaccess but hyperlink redirects to folder index not php

Tags: .htaccess, hide

On my server I am using this .htaccess to remove the .PHP extension:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

And it works fine, /about goes to the about.php page and /contact to the .contact.php file. However I have a projects.php and a projects folder so the hyperlink redirects to the folder index. I understand I could simply rename either the php or folder and solve the problem, but if I have subfolders in the projects folders, I won't be able to keep the URL as /projects/photography
Here is an image to help explain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKjEF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/projects$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It should work with DirectorySlash off, but see [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258879/apache-directoryslash-off-site-breaks). If you don't like them you are better off renaming projects.php

Comment: domain.com/projects automatically links to domain.com/projects/ (with the extra slash) and links to the index still

Comment: @PrestonMcPeak Try edited version that allows optional trailing slash

Comment: @PrestonMcPeak I already made the necessary edits above :-). Let me know if it works

Comment: Nope :/ it still chooses the folder over the .PHP

Comment: @PrestonMcPeak When DirectorySlash was on `/projects` was 301 redirected to `/projects/` and your browser is caching the redirect. Try this solution in private browsing mode and you will see it work. I have tested it myself.